# Weird owner-drawn-variable combo box behavior

Tags: .net, combobox, scroll

In my .NET owner-drawn-variable combo box, when I move by page or by mouse wheel, it appears to scroll in the WRONG DIRECTION, but then ends up on the right item.

Nothing seems to avoid this behavior.  I tried making it owner-drawn-fixed, but it then changed the size of the combo box.

How can I make it scroll normally?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try to create window using CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED style instead of CBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE

Comment: Using OwnerDrawFixed for the combobox is certainly the solution if it's possible for you. I don't know how to work around the problem if you must use OwnerDrawVariable.